# How do I compare SUM and COUNT()s in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am building a small query to find all CustomerNumbers where all of their policies are in a certain status (terminated).

Here is the query I am working on

```
    select 
    a.cn
    ,p.pn
    , tp = COUNT(p.pn)
    , tp2 = SUM(case when p.status = 4 then 1 else 0 end)
from
(
        select cn, cn2
        from bc
        union 
        select cn, cn2= fn
        from ic
) as a
left join p as p
on a.cn = p.cn

group by 
    a.cn, 
    pn
```

My issue is when I add the clause:

```
   WHERE cn = tp
```

It says the columns are invalid. Am I missing something incredibly obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use aliases at the same level of a query.  The reason is that the `where` clause is *logically* evaluated before the `select`, so the aliases defined in the `select` are not available in the `where`.

A typical solution is to repeat the expression (other answers) or use a subquery or cte:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select cte.*
from cte
where TotalPolicies = TermedPolicies;
```

However, in your case, you have an easier solution, because you have an aggregation query.  So just use:

```
having TotalPolicies = TermedPolicies
```

Comment: +1 I would choose your answer `having TotalPolicies = TermedPolicies` is way much simplier :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the aliased aggregate column names in the where clause. You have to use the expression itself instead. Also you cannot use it as where cluase, but use it in the having clause

```
HAVING COUNT(p.PolicyNumber) = SUM(case when p.status = 4 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make the whole query as a subquery then add your where statement:

```
select CustomerNumber
       ,PolicyNumber
       ,TotalPolicies
       ,TermedPolicies
  from (
    select 
        a.CustomerNumber
        ,p.PolicyNumber
        , TotalPolicies = COUNT(p.PolicyNumber)
        , TermedPolicies = SUM(case when p.status = 4 then 1 else 0 end)
    from
    (
            select CustomerNumber, CompanyName
            from BusinessClients 
            union 
            select CustomerNumber, CompanyName = FullName
            from IndividualClients
    ) as a
    left join Policies as p
    on a.CustomerNumber = p.CustomerNumber
    group by 
        a.CustomerNumber, 
        PolicyNumber
    ) tb
where TotalPolicies = TermedPolicies
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select 
    a.CustomerNumber
    ,p.PolicyNumber
    , COUNT(p.PolicyNumber) as TotalPolicies 
    , SUM(case when p.status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as TermedPolicies 
from
(
        select CustomerNumber, CompanyName
        from BusinessClients 
        union 
        select CustomerNumber, CompanyName = FullName
        from IndividualClients
) as a
left join Policies as p
on a.CustomerNumber = p.CustomerNumber
WHERE COUNT(p.PolicyNumber)= SUM(case when p.status = 4 then 1 else 0 end)
group by 
    a.CustomerNumber, 
    PolicyNumber
```

This should work. But it is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter by an aggregate function, you must include it in the `HAVING` clause, rather than the `WHERE` clause.

```
select 
    a.CustomerNumber
    ,p.PolicyNumber
    , TotalPolicies = COUNT(p.PolicyNumber)
    , TermedPolicies = SUM(case when p.status = 4 then 1 else 0 end)
from
(
        select CustomerNumber, CompanyName
        from BusinessClients 
        union 
        select CustomerNumber, CompanyName = FullName
        from IndividualClients
) as a
left join Policies as p
on a.CustomerNumber = p.CustomerNumber
having COUNT(p.PolicyNumber) = SUM(case when p.status = 4 then 1 else 0 end)
group by 
    a.CustomerNumber, 
    PolicyNumber
```

The reason for this has to do with the way SQL engines evaluate queries. The contents of the `WHERE` clause are used to filter out rows before the aggregate functions are applied. If you could reference aggregate functions there, the engine would have to have some way to determine which predicates to apply before aggregation and which to apply after. The `HAVING` clause allows the engine to have a clear demarcation between the two: `WHERE` applies before aggregation and `HAVING` applies after aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with aggregations in a query that has grouping, you will need to use [HAVING](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php). This should work:

```
select 
a.CustomerNumber
,p.PolicyNumber
, TotalPolicies = COUNT(p.PolicyNumber)
, TermedPolicies = SUM(case when p.status = 4 then 1 else 0 end)
from
(
        select CustomerNumber, CompanyName
        from BusinessClients 
        union 
        select CustomerNumber, CompanyName = FullName
        from IndividualClients
) as a
left join Policies as p
on a.CustomerNumber = p.CustomerNumber

group by 
    a.CustomerNumber, 
    PolicyNumber
HAVING TermedPolicies = SUM(case when p.status = 4 then 1 else 0 end)
```